# How to apply an outline for a text in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, raphael

I have a site for customize football jersey design. I'm using Raphael.js  customization and I need to know how we can apply **outline** for a text in Raphael.

On searching, I got the suggestion of using the **stroke property** of Raphael. But this is not giving an outline effect. Stroke is actually Inline. When we increase stroke width, the width of the text will decrease.

How do I apply outline for a text in Raphael without reducing width of text?

Text before stroke : [image: Text before applying stroke]

Text after stroke: [image: Text after applying stroke]

Text needs to be like this on applying stroke/outline (just demo from photoshop): [image: text need to be like this on applying stroke (just demo from photoshop)]

Comment: `var paper = Raphael("playarea", 500, 500);

var text = paper.text(200, 100, "RAPHAEL!!");
text.attr({ "font-size": 100, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","stroke":"red","stroke-width":"5px"});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
text.attr({ 
        "font-size": 100, 
        "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
        "stroke":"red",
        "stroke-width":"5px",
        "stroke-linecap": "square",
        "stroke-linejoin": "bevel"});
```

Comment: issue is still there. Stroke is applying by reducing test width.When we increase stroke width it is reducing the width of text.

Answer (score 0):

"The paint-order attribute specifies the order that the fill, stroke, and markers of a given shape or text element are painted."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/paint-order

What you want would be

```
var paper = Raphael("playarea", 500, 500); 
var text = paper.text(200, 100, "RAPHAEL!!"); 
text.attr({ "font-size": 100, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", "stroke":"red", "stroke-width":"5px", "paint-order":"stroke"});
```

Dan, expanding on the example you gave

Beware for IE does not support

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. An easy solution is to add the text twice at the same position. First add text in the color you want the stroke to be, and add your stroke. Then, add the text again with the desired fill color and no stroke. Adjust the stroke width on the first text element until you achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).